# How was the explicit closed form for this implicit function derived?

Tags: statistics, self-learning

The problem comes from reading [this [0]](http://www3.stat.sinica.edu.tw/statistica/oldpdf/A6n25.pdf) paper but I think I can express it in a self contained question.

---

Consider the implicit function $H(z)$ defined by the relation:

$$F_z(z+H(z))-F_z(z-H(z))=0.5$$

Where $F_z$ is the CDF of an absolutly continuous, unimodal distribution.

The authors point out that when $F'_z=f_z=\max(1-|z|,0)$ (the triangle distribution with parameters $a=-1,c=0$ and $b=1$),

$$H(z)= \begin{cases}
   1-\sqrt{1/2-z^2} & \text{if } |z| \leq 1/2 \\
   |z|       & \text{if } |z| > 1/2
  \end{cases}$$

(p387, bottom of the article I linked to)

My questions are:

- How was the explicit formulation for $H(z)$ derived?
- Can it also be done for other values of $c$, i.e. $c=1$

---

[0] Ola Hössjer, Peter J. Rousseeuw and Christophe Croux.  Asymptotics of an estimator of a robust spread functional. Statistica Sinica 6(1996), 375-388.

Comment: $f=F$? I guess that it is true.

Comment: @Mike: I don't understand your comment ;(

Comment: I don't understand why this was migrated. It looks totally on-topic at the original location to me.

Comment: @user1963. Please ignore my comment.  I did not see $F'=f$ when I made the comment.

Comment: @Mike: that's ok, I added this as a response to your comment! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a piecewise formula for $f_z$.
$$
f_z(z) = \begin{cases}
 z+1 & -1\leq z\leq 0 \\
 1-z & 0\leq z\leq 1 \\
 0 & \text{else}.
\end{cases}
$$
Computing a formula for $F_z$ is just a matter of integrating.
$$
F_z(z) = \int_{-1}^z f_z(z) \, dz = 
\begin{cases}
 0 & z\leq -1 \\
 \frac{z^2}{2}+z+\frac{1}{2} &
   -1<z\leq 0 \\
 -\frac{z^2}{2}+z+\frac{1}{2} &
   0<z\leq 1 \\
 1 & z>1.
\end{cases}
$$
Note that the constants are chosen to ensure continuity.  With this, your implicit formula
$$F_z(z+H(z))-F_z(z-H(z))=1/2$$
can be analyzed on certain intervals.  Suppose, for example, that $0\leq z+H(z) \leq 1$ and that $-1\leq z-H(z) \leq 0$, which imples that $-1/2\leq z \leq 1/2$. Then the implicit formula becomes
$$\left(-\frac{1}{2}(z+H(z))^2 + (z+H(z)) + 1/2\right) - \left(\frac{1}{2}(z-H(z))^2 + (z-H(z)) + 1/2)\right) = \frac{1}{2}.$$
Solving this formula for $H(Z)$ yields the formula for $H(z)$ yields the portion of your piecewise expression valid for $-1/2\leq z \leq 1/2$.  The other terms follow in similar fashion.

I'm certain that a similar thing can be done with different choices of your constant $c$.

Comment: Thanks: I am wondering whether the first '-1/2' in the formula after 'Then the implicit formula becomes' shouldn't be '+1/2'. Can you confirm?

Comment: @user1963 I don't believe so. The assumption in the previous paragraph is that $0<z+H(z)\leq1$ and, according to the piecewise definition of $F_z(arg)$, we should use the version of $F_z$ with the leading minus sign, when $0<arg\leq1$.  Note that $arg$ here stands for "argument" and I'm trying to distinguish that argument from $z$; in this case, the argument is $z+H(z)$. Also, I solved the equation in Mathematica and it seemed to give the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. One more question: I beleive that solving the equation (below 'then the implicit formula becomes') for H(z) yields two roots, the first one corresponds with the answer in the paper, why do we exclude the second root?

Comment: @user1963 Honestly, I picked the one that led to the answer you wanted. :)  I suspect that the other root is excluded by the assumptions $0\leq z+H(z) \leq 1$ and $-1\leq z-H(z) \leq 0$, but I didn't check.